# Symfony 4 production WebProfiler route

Tags: symfony, routes, bundle, production

I try to change a Symfony 4.4 in production mode but after executing this command line from the documentation : APP_ENV=prod APP_DEBUG=0 php bin/console cache:clear

I get this error :

```
Bundle "WebProfilerBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your App\Kernel.php file? in @WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml (which is being imported from "/home/admin/mercenaries/config/routes/dev/web_profiler.yaml")
```

The env is correct because the bundle is not loaded.
But how do I do for cancel this routes/dev repository to load ?

Comment: I've the same problem, any solution ?

Comment: No, I have deleted the routing dev file ...